# Python regex to split last dollar value

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a regex script using python and re package where the last dollar value is split from the string.

This is what I have so far:

```
import re
str = ['2 Apple pie $1.50 /each: $3.00',
   'Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR3 1600 MHz (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory $34.99']

[re.split("([$]\d+\.\d{2}?)",i) for i in str]
```

**Output:**

```
[['2 Apple pie ', '$1.50', ' /each: ', '$3.00', ''],
 ['Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR3 1600 MHz (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory ','$34.99','']]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[['2 Apple pie $1.50 /each: ', '$3.00'],
 ['Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR3 1600 MHz (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory ','$34.99']]
```

Any pointers would help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `rsplit`? `[i.rsplit("$", 1) for i in str]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make this work with your example:

```
import re
str = ['2 Apple pie $1.50 /each: $3.00',
   'Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR3 1600 MHz (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory $34.99']

output = [re.match(r"(.+)(\$.*)$", x).groups() for x in str]
print output
# [('2 Apple pie $1.50 /each: ', '$3.00'), ('Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR3 1600 MHz (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory ', '$34.99')]
```

The regex takes advantage of the fact that regex is greedy, so by letting it gobble up as many characters as it can before looking for a `$` with some characters behind it, we're able to implicitly tell the regex engine to split on the last `$`.

Comment: I like this answer more because it seems the OP tries to make split do the same thing as groups() on a match object. At least the usage of the capturing group in the pattern indicates that somewhat.

Comment: Thanks, but @marcospereira's answer should be the right answer. It's succinct, clean, and easy to read.

Comment: If you can be sure that the end of the string is always a price and that you don't care for the dollar sign, that's true

Comment: @shmee Oh, I didn't even realize that it "ate" the dollar sign. That changes my mind a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't split with a zero-width match with the re module but it's possible to use this pattern `(?=[$][0-9.]+$)` with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
[regex.split("(?V1)(?=[$][0-9.]+$)", i) for i in str]
```

However, you can use the space before the dollar sign to make it works with the re module:

```
[re.split(" (?=[$][0-9.]+$)",i) for i in str]
```

Comment: Your solution fails if the last dollar sign is not at the end of the string. `str.append("This is a $34.50 string with $45.20 random dollar signs"); [re.split(" (?=[$][0-9.]+$)",i) for i in str];` produces the wrong result in the last element.

Comment: @brittenb: Yes but as you can see, the strings have always the price *at the end* (otherwise the question has no sense).